# writing a cell reference formula using user define range

Tags: excel, vba, formula

This is a pretty simple question... I just am getting stuck on the syntax.

How can I change this formula to make it vba legal:

```
    Dim sum_rng As Range
    Set sum_rng = Range(Cells(strt_pt(end_ct), j), Cells(end_pt(end_ct), j))
    'Debug.Print sum_rng

    Cells(47, lent + 2).Formula = "=AVERAGE(IF(ISNUMBER(" & sum_rng & ")," & sum_rng & ")"
```

The arrays and everything else looks fine, I think the issue is the .Formula vs. .FormulaR1C1 or something else.

Comment: Try this `Cells(47, lent + 2).Formula = "=AVERAGE(IF(ISNUMBER(" & sum_rng.Address & ")," & sum_rng.Address & "))"` EDIT: Added the Bracket after seeing asantaballa's post

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing a paren. See end of last line

```
Dim sum_rng As Range
Set sum_rng = Range(Cells(strt_pt(end_ct), j), Cells(end_pt(end_ct), j))
'Debug.Print sum_rng

Cells(47, lent + 2).Formula = "=AVERAGE(IF(ISNUMBER(" & sum_rng & ")," & sum_rng & "))"
```

Comment: hm should i also put in .address. asantaballa's solution by itself isnt printing the formula to the cell

Comment: actually it works... only thing is it returns a zero value for all cells.. I think i need to make the formula an array formula as in <i> "{=AVERAGE....)}" but I'm not sure how to do this

Comment: I'd give a shot @SiddharthRout solution with address. I think he's on the right track and you just needed to get by the syntax problem with the paren.

Comment: hey thanks guys yeah i used both of your codes... <i>  "=AVERAGE(IF(ISNUMBER(" & sum_rng.Address & ")," & sum_rng.Address & "))" <i>